# How can I move an account into the main/primary organization unit?

Tags: python, google-provisioning-api

Using the Google Provisioning API, under [Managing Organization Units](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#managing_organization_users), I can use `UpdateOrgUser` to change the OU in which a user resides.

How I can move a user out of an OU and into the "top-level" OU? What should be passed to `org_unit_path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top-level OU can be referenced with a single slash. You can move users into the root OU by setting the orgUnitPath to "/".

Comment: Not that I could find. Sub-organizations are separated by slashes and updating a user with the orgUnitPath set to a single slash moved them to them to the root when I tested it.

Comment: It's my understanding that using / to put the user back in the top level org only works with the update org user API call: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#updating_an_organization_user_experimental it won't work with the org unit update bulk user move API call: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#updating_an_organization_unit_experimental

Comment: I don't believe the "Updating an Organization Unit (Experimental)" can be used to move users. It is used to modify properties of the OU itself, such as the name or the parent OU. Those don't apply to the root since it can't be renamed or moved.